# Fixed Header and Auto Scrolling To Div's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using the following script to make scroll to a section within the page when clicked on it's link from the top navigation menu in the header

So basically in the HTML I have assigned ID's to each section (sectio1, section2, section3 etc.), and I have also assigned these section in the top navigation href's for example `<a href="#about">About us</a>`. So when you click on About us from the top navigation it will take you to the Div that have an ID of `#about.`

The scrolling bit is working, however, because my Header is Fixed - when it scrolls to the section the top bit of that section appears cropped since the header is overlaying it. click here for a live preview: www.loaistudio.com What can I do about this? also what can I do to add to the below JavaScript to make it when you scroll to a section it actually gives its link from the navigation a class of Active?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') 
            || location.hostname == this.hostname) {

            var target = $(this.hash);
            target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
               if (target.length) {
                 $('html,body').animate({
                     scrollTop: target.offset().top
                }, 700);
                return false;
            }
        }
    });   
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Scrolling

Simple solution would be to alter the `scrollTop` to factor in the height of the menu bar...

Something like:

```
scrollTop: target.offset().top - 186
```

You could also get the height dynamically if the menu isn't a fixed height.

---

### Active Link

You could do this by having the scroll event trigger and then checking whether `scrollTop` is between heights `x and y` for Home or `y and z` for About etc..

Okay you can use the following code...

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var scrollHeight = $(window).scrollTop() + 186;
    
    var welcomeOffset     = $('#Welcome').offset().top;
    var aboutOffset       = $('#About').offset().top;
    var portfolioOffset   = $('#Portfolio').offset().top;
    var endorsementOffset = $('#Endorsements').offset().top;
    var contactOffset     = $('#Contact').offset().top;
    
    var foreColor = "777";
    var backColor = "FAFAFA";
    
    $('#mainMenu li a').css({background:"#FFFFFF", color: "#F58221"})
    if(scrollHeight >= welcomeOffset && scrollHeight < aboutOffset){
        $('#mainMenu :nth-child(1) a').css({background:"#"+backColor, color:"#"+foreColor})
    }
    if(scrollHeight >= aboutOffset && scrollHeight < portfolioOffset){
        $('#mainMenu :nth-child(2) a').css({background:"#"+backColor, color:"#"+foreColor})
    }
    if(scrollHeight >= portfolioOffset && scrollHeight < endorsementOffset){
        $('#mainMenu :nth-child(4) a').css({background:"#"+backColor, color:"#"+foreColor})
    }
    if(scrollHeight >= endorsementOffset && scrollHeight < contactOffset){
        $('#mainMenu :nth-child(3) a').css({background:"#"+backColor, color:"#"+foreColor})
    }
    if(scrollHeight >= contactOffset){
        $('#mainMenu :nth-child(5) a').css({background:"#"+backColor, color:"#"+foreColor})
    }
})
```

The above code can go in `<script>...</script>` tags anywhere where you would put other `jquery` you could also put it just before (or after) your code that you've already shown... I.e. just above (or below)

```
$(document).ready(function () {.....})
```

If you want to test it before adding to your site you can simply put it into something like Firefox *scratchpad* (have your page open and press `SHIFT+F4` in Firefox) then copy/paste the above code in and hit `CTRL+R` then scroll up and down to see it working.

---

### To clarify how the codes should do together

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var scrollHeight = $(window).scrollTop() + 186;
    
    var welcomeOffset     = $('#Welcome').offset().top;
    var aboutOffset       = $('#About').offset().top;
    var portfolioOffset   = $('#Portfolio').offset().top;
    var endorsementOffset = $('#Endorsements').offset().top;
    var contactOffset     = $('#Contact').offset().top;
    
    var foreColor = "777";
    var backColor = "FAFAFA";
    
    $('#mainMenu li a').css({background:"#FFFFFF", color: "#F58221"})
    if(scrollHeight >= welcomeOffset && scrollHeight < aboutOffset){
        $('#mainMenu :nth-child(1) a').css({background:"#"+backColor, color:"#"+foreColor})
    }
    if(scrollHeight >= aboutOffset && scrollHeight < portfolioOffset){
        $('#mainMenu :nth-child(2) a').css({background:"#"+backColor, color:"#"+foreColor})
    }
    if(scrollHeight >= portfolioOffset && scrollHeight < endorsementOffset){
        $('#mainMenu :nth-child(4) a').css({background:"#"+backColor, color:"#"+foreColor})
    }
    if(scrollHeight >= endorsementOffset && scrollHeight < contactOffset){
        $('#mainMenu :nth-child(3) a').css({background:"#"+backColor, color:"#"+foreColor})
    }
    if(scrollHeight >= contactOffset){
        $('#mainMenu :nth-child(5) a').css({background:"#"+backColor, color:"#"+foreColor})
    }
})


$(document).ready(function () {
            $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') 
            || location.hostname == this.hostname) {

            var target = $(this.hash);
            target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
               if (target.length) {
                 $('html,body').animate({
                     scrollTop: target.offset().top
                }, 700);
                return false;
            }
        }
    });   
    });
```

Comment: Thank you the height problem has been fixed! I was playing around that area but never got it right! I thought we will have to have the numbers inside the () after the offset!!! However regarding the Active links... I am abit confused of how or where to implement

Comment: one down, one to go! Okay, give me a second and I'll try to put together something/explain it :)

Comment: Right, sorry for the delay.. Anyway, see the updated answer for some working `jquery` which does as you need. **NOTE:** I have used the height value 186 for the menu you may need to change that (if you changed it earlier). Also, you may need to change the colour variables `foreColor` and `backColor` for _active_ and the colours in the line above the first `if` statement for _non-active_.

Comment: Thank you, but I am struggling to actually place is with the old code, how would the new code look like? like all of them together please it keep giving me errors and I am sure I am placing it in the wrong place

Comment: Okay, see the update.. If you still get an error, let me know what it is!

Comment: It worked mate thank you! but I don't really understand what are the fore and back colours?

Comment: I suggest you change them to something like `f00` and `0f0` to make it obvious what they are; but, they are the `css` `color` and `background` attributes for your menu buttons/links.

Comment: hmmm, mate there is no way to make it take that from the CSS? as in addClass / removeClass? please if there is any easy way! Will be much grateful!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37967/discussion-between-loai-and-steven)

Comment: Just updated / uploaded the new version to the server www.loaistudio.com - the height thing isn't working anymore now mate, what I am doing wrong?